# Getting date from Django datetime field with F() expression

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a Django model object that requires to update a particular field if the `last_updated` datetime field is equal to today's date.

If I were to use F expression to avoid race condition, what would be the best way to compare the date from `last_updated` with current date using `timezone.now().date()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, `F()` can't do that operation. So I would suggest another way to achieve the same by using  [**Extract()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#extract)

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractDay, ExtractMonth, ExtractYear

queryset = SampleModel.objects.annotate(day=ExtractDay('last_updated'),
                                        month=ExtractMonth('last_updated'),
                                        year=ExtractYear('last_updated')
                                        ).filter(day=timezone.now().day,
                                                 month=timezone.now().month,
                                                 year=timezone.now().year
                                                 )
```

This will return a `QuerySet()`, So you can fetch a specific instance by `.get()` method as below,

```
specific_model_instance = queryset.get(id=specific_id)
```

Note: I know this is litle bit long procedure. But it'll work

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to filter based on date, and your model has a `DateTime` field, you can simply use Django's `__date` lookup:

`MyModel.objects.filter(last_updated__date=timezone.now().date()).update(...)`

Also, as a general note, remember that your code's timezone behavior will affect comparisons between timestamps and dates (i.e. the same timestamp might correspond to different dates depending on which timezone is in use).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something using [the conditional update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-update) instead.

So something along the lines of:

```
Client.objects.update(
  other_field=Case(
    When(last_updated__eq=datetime.date.today(),
         then=Value('OTHER_FIELD_VALUE'))
  )
)
```